# problem showing data using getters in vuex

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

i am using vuex with vue cli. i am fetching data from a database and i am trying to filter out specific data using getters. i am using the filter method on the array, when i return the data and try to show it in the html it shows the full array, when i console.log it shows the correct information

```
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    customerData: []
  },
  actions: {
    fetchData: ({ commit }) => {
      return axios
        .get("/customer")
        .then(({ data }) => {
          const { customers } = data;
          commit("loadData", customers);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error, "error"));
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    loadData: (state, projects) => {
      state.customerData = projects;
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getDate: state => {
      return state.customerData.filter(data => {
        return data.date
      });
    }
  }
};
```

returning the data like so from the getDate returns the whole array to the screen.

```
getters: {
    getDate: state => {
      return state.customerData.filter(data => {
        return console.log(data.date)
      });
    }
  }
```

console logging the data like so will show the correct data that i want. im not sure what im doing wrong. i basically copied the code from the vuex documentation but it will not work

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div v-for="item in customerData" :key="item.id">
      <p>{{ item.first_name }} {{ item.last_name }}</p>
    </div>
    <h1>{{getDate}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapState, mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData();
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState("data", ["customerData"]),
    ...mapGetters("data", ["getDate"])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("data", ["fetchData"])
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to only return users with a date and remove the ones without a date or empty date? Otherwise you are after map.

Comment: All my users will have a date. I’m trying to filter out each date in the database and return that data if that makes sense

Comment: so Filter is used to well... filter out objects. but how you are using it does not make sense. say you were looking to only get the customer data that had a date under 1 year ago. change it to map

Answer (score 0):

In your component, there are 2 computed props:

- `customerData`. This is defined by `...mapState("data", ["customerData"])` in your code. It stores the entire list of customers
- `getDate`. This is defined by `...mapGetters("data", ["getDate"])`. This computed property is storing the list of filtered users.

In you HTML, you are running a loop over `customerData` which shows the entire list:

`<div v-for="item in customerData" :key="item.id">`

Instead, you need to run loop over `getDate` like this:

`<div v-for="item in getDate" :key="item.id">`

Once you change this, you'll see the list of filtered users.

Side Note: Please consider changing the getter name to `filteredCustomerData` instead of `getDate`.